# disabling text box in html?

Tags: javascript, html

i've got some js code that populates an input field with a name, when a number is selected. once the name is populated, it can't be edited.

the problem is, when i disable the field and submit the form, it doesn't submit the disabled value. and i can't seem to make the field work by making it a readonly field. what other options do i have?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it readonly, not disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly populate the value into a hidden input, then make the initial input disabled? Not sure if that's what you're looking for but that would be pretty easy to pull of in jQuery.